# Syncing docker images

Tags: docker

I have 2 machines(separate hosts) running docker and I am using the same image on both the machines. How do I keep both the images in sync. For eg. suppose I make changes to the image in one of the hosts and want the changes to reflect in the other host as well. I can commit the image and copy the image over to the other host. Is there any other efficient way of doing this??

Comment: Are you using any image registry? Do you want the images to be synced automatically without copying or pushing/pulling?

Comment: @vivekyad4v  am not using a registry as of now. If a registry is used I can push to the registry and pull from it right ? Yeah I want kinda automatic sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ways I can think of:

#### 1. with a Docker registry

the workflow here is:

- HOST A: `docker commit`, `docker push`
- HOST B: `docker pull`

#### 2. by saving the image to a `.tar` file

the workflow here is:

- HOST A: `docker save`
- HOST B: `docker load`

#### 3. with a `Dockerfile` and by building the image again

the workflow here is:

- provide a `Dockerfile` together with your code / files required
- everytime your code has changed and you want to make a release, use `docker build` to create a new image.
- from the hosts that you want to take the update, you will have to get the updated source code (maybe by using a version control software like Git), and then `docker build` the image

#### 4. CI/CD pipeline

you can see a video here: [docker.com/use-cases/cicd](https://www.docker.com/use-cases/cicd)

---

Keep in mind that `containers` are considered to be *ephemeral*. This means that updating an `image` inside another host will then require:

1. to `stop` and `remove` any old container (running with the outdated image)
2. to `run` a new one (with the updated image)

I quote from: [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

> ### General guidelines and recommendations
>
> #### Containers should be ephemeral
>
> The container produced by the image your Dockerfile defines should be as ephemeral as possible. **By “ephemeral,” we mean that it can be stopped and destroyed and a new one built and put in place with an absolute minimum of set-up and configuration**.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform `docker push` to upload you image to `docker registry` and perform a `docker pull` to get the latest image from another host.

For more information please look at [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/)

Comment: I guess he wants the images to be synced automatically without copying or pushing/pulling, as per @vignesh - "I can commit the image and copy the image over to the other host". Probably he is not using any registry otherwise `push` & `pull` is the way to go.

Comment: I was thinking he using the `save` and `load` way without going thru registry since he did not mention `registry` at all